# Help needed with removing adhesive

Tags: vinyl-flooring

Trying to get up the paper left after removing floor covering . Used concentrated adhesive remover not working very well. Been working on it for two days now. It’s on plywood need advice

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What kind of floor covering did you remove? Why do you need all the paper removed? Would you be able to post a picture?

Comment: Also, is it on the plywood subfloor, or is it on a thinner sheet of plywood that's stapled down to the subfloor?  If you're trying to remove paper I'd hazard a guess that it was glued-down paper-backed vinyl, but we need more information to be able to help.